# For loope breaks on satisfied internal if statement

Tags: java, android, loops

In project I have following method, which iterate through Genre enum, also presented below. The problem is that when if statement is satisfied for some value the for loop breaks and the method returns false. What could be wrong with this piece of code?

Thanks.

```
private boolean genreExists(Integer num) {
    Genre[] genres = Genre.values();
    for(Genre g : genres){
        if(num == g.getId()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public enum Genre {
ACTION(28),
ADVENNTURE(12),
ANIMATION(16),
COMEDY(35),
CRIME(80),
DOCUMENTARY(99),
DRAMA(18),
FAMILY(10751),
FANTASY(14),
HISTORY(36),
HORROR(27),
MUSIC(10402),
MYSTERY(9648),
ROMANCE(10749),
SCIENCEFICTION(878),
TVMOVIE(10770),
THRILLER(53),
WAR(10752),
WESTERN(37);

private static final Map<Integer, Genre> map = new HashMap<>();

static{
    for(Genre g : values()){
        map.put(g.getId(), g);
    }
}

int id;

Genre(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public static Genre of(Integer id){
    Genre result = map.get(id);
    if(result == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid id value: " + id);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: That would be because the if statement is true. 
What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, that on satisfied if statement method indeed should break, but it should return true. Now on satisfied if statement the loop breaks and return false.

Comment: The return statement inside the if does exactly that. It returns true

Comment: Did you try to debug? Or simply print out what is going on? For example, in for loop, print out what is g.getId()? The code seems okay. Hard to see without debugging.

Comment: You should check to see if `Genre of(Integer id)` method works - it has a different return type, but is basically doing the same thing - locating a valid `Genre` if exists.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps what you should be doing is this:

```
boolean cond = false;
for(Genre g : genres){
    if(num == g.getId()){
        cond = true;
        break;   
    }
}
return cond;
```

And if you're still getting false returned then your IF condition is never met.